# R: geom_ribbon() data transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Idea is to produce graph with multiple lines and ribbon around one particular line.

Here's the data:

```
x <- data.table(a = 1:10, y = runif(10, 1, 2), z = runif(10, 1, 2))
x[,y_h:=y+.2]
x[,y_l:=y-.2]
x <- melt(x, id.vars = ("a"), variable.factor = F)
```

This produces line graph:

```
ggplot(x[variable %in% c("y", "z")], aes(x = a, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal()
```

This produces ribbon graph:

```
ggplot(data = dcast(x[variable %in% c("y_h", "y_l")], a ~ variable, value.var = "value"),  
       aes(x = a, ymin = y_l, ymax = y_h)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha = .3) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Combining both produces error:

```
ggplot(x[variable %in% c("y", "z")], aes(x = a, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_ribbon(data = dcast(x[variable %in% c("y_h", "y_l")], a ~ variable, value.var = "value"), 
              aes(x = a, ymin = y_l, ymax = y_h), alpha = .3)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found
```

I know that multiple lines require data in long format and ribbon requires wide format for columns to feed into `ymin` and `ymax`. This error message doesn't really help to determine the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've got the answer myself, right after posting the question.

Here:

```
ggplot(data = dcast(x[variable %in% c("y_h", "y_l")], a ~ variable, value.var = "value")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = a, ymin = y_l, ymax = y_h), alpha = .3) +
  geom_line(data = x[variable %in% c("y", "z")], aes(x = a, y = value, color = variable)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I guess the issue was setting `aes()` variables globally for `geom_ribbon()`, under `ggplot()` call. Apparently it messes up subsequent `aes()`, even if you explicitly define them for each following `geom`. However, the error message still kind of threw me off the correct path.